# Neo4j + bolt + c#; how do you create multiple nodes via one query by passing a map as a parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, neo4j

can anyone advise how I should change my code (this is based on section 3.5.1.4.2 from the 3.0 developer manual). I am trying to create multiple nodes via one query in bolt.

```
using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(Neo4jCredentials.Instance, AuthTokens.Basic(Neo4jCredentials.Username, Neo4jCredentials.Password))) 

using (var session = driver.Session())
{
string query = "UNWIND { props } AS map CREATE(n) SET n = map";
                Dictionary<string, object> myParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                myParameter.Add("props", "{\"props\":[{\"name\":\"Andres\",\"position\":\"Developer\"},{\"name\":\"Michael\",\"position\":\"Developer\"}]}");
                return session.Run(query, myParameter);
            }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
{"Expected map to be a map, but it was :`{\"props\":[{\"name\":\"Andres\",\"position\":\"Developer\"},{\"name\":\"Michael\",\"position\":\"Developer\"}]}`"}
```

Thanks in advance my learned friends...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try forming your dictionary of params using an array of dictionaries:

```
    Dictionary<string, object> myParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    Dictionary<string, object>[] props =
    {
        new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "Andres"}, {"position", "Developer"}},
        new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "Michael"}, {"position", "Developer"}}
    };
    myParameter.Add("props",props);
```

or with a few less characters:

```
var myParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {
        "props", new[]
        {
            new Dictionary<string, string> {{"name", "Andres"}, {"position", "Developer"}},
            new Dictionary<string, string> {{"name", "Michael"}, {"position", "Developer"}}
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This is stilll the case even with the current version of Cypher at the time this comment was posted. Reading on how to do a CREATE with parameters on this link (https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create/) makes you think that you need to use some almost JSON formatted string data but that does not work. Using the dictionary solution as described above works correctly with the official Neo4j C# driver.